# How Can I Constrain an XML Element's Validity Based Upon One Of Its Attribute's Values within XSD?

Tags: xml, properties, xsd

If I have the following XML:

```
<properties>
    <parameter key="number">1</parameter>
    <parameter key="letter">A</parameter>
</properties>
```

...and I want the backing XSD for "properties" to enforce that all "parameter" tags with a "key" attribute of "number" accept only numbers for their text content, and all with "letter" to accept only letters, is it possible to represent that constraint scenario using XSD?  If not, is it possible to do so under any other schema language?

Please note that I am of course fully aware that I could do:

```
<properties>
    <number>1</number>
    <letter>A</letter>
</properties>
```

...but this exercise has as its aim the possibility of compressing more complex scenarios than such as represented immediately above.

In short, I am looking for a methodology for constructing a 'non-verbose' XML-based properties file capable of handling potentially complex value constraints, including even the possible constraint
of attributes living on the same level as "attr" or "key" in the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pretty intuitive XSD 1.1 for your problem. It is based on [type alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org">
    <xsd:element name="properties">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="parameter">
        <xsd:alternative test="@key eq 'number'" type="number"/>
        <xsd:alternative test="@key eq 'letter'" type="letter"/>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="number">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="number"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="letter">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="aletter">
                <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="letter"/>             
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="aletter">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

An invalid XML, such as:

```
<properties>
    <parameter key="number">A</parameter>
    <parameter key="letter">1</parameter>
</properties>
```

Would yield the following output (I am using my own tool, [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com), which uses Xerces for XSD 1.1).

> Error while loading [], line 2 position 42 cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1:
> 'A' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
>
> Error while loading [], line 2
> position 42 cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'parameter' must have no
> element [children], and the value must be valid.
>
> Error while loading
> [], line 3 position 42 cvc-pattern-valid: Value '1' is not facet-valid
> with respect to pattern '[A-Z]' for type 'aletter'.
>
> Error while
> loading [], line 3 position 42 cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element
> 'parameter' must have no element [children], and the value must be
> valid.